# Upload csv data time to snowflake

Tags: time, types, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a csv data file to upload to Snowflake. It has a column called Year-month with data like this: 2020-10, 2020-11, etc.
How could I upload the csv file to Snowflake? Which type of data does the Year-month column have?
Thanks

Comment: Dont think you will be able to put this into a datatype related to date or timestamp. You will have to load them as strings and then later work on them as needed. How do you plan to use these values?

Comment: I plan to aggregate values in another column based on conditions using Year-month column

Comment: Try and use date_from_parts as conversion while loading data. This will load year-mm as date datatype in your table. Once its loaded as date type, you can perform aggregation on that as needed.  select DATE_FROM_PARTS(split_part('2010-01','-',1),split_part('2010-01','-',2),01);